# Using event based API in a thread (blocking mode)

Tags: c++, multithreading, events, visual-c++, bluetooth

In my C++ application I'm using a third party library for Bluetooth discovering process. I'm looking at the examples provided to learn how to use it.

The example that best match my needs is a simple GUI application that call a `Discovery(long timeout)` function from the library to start the Bluetooth discovery.
That function returns immediatly (so that the GUI is not freezed) and fires an `__event` called `OnDeviceFound` once a new BT device has been discovered and `OnDiscoveryComplete` once the `timeout` has elapsed.

So in the GUI constructor (of the example) there're `__hook` defined like this:

```
__hook(&BluetoothDiscovery::OnDiscoveryComplete, &m_Discovery, &BluetoothClientDlg::OnDiscoveryComplete);
```

Now, I need to implement the same in my application, that is not a Window application but a console application that runs as a Windows Service, doing a continuos discovering on a separate thread looking for new devices.

So, actually, since my implementation makes use of a thread for discovery, I don't need an event based discovery procedure, but I need a blocking discovering. The library does not provide a blocking API for discovering.

So here comes the question: is it possible to use an event based function in a blocking function? In other words, is it possible to write a function that could be called in the thread main loop every *n* seconds that does a discovery procedure and return the founded Bluetooth devices (using that event-based library API)?

Comment: Please note that the event is raised each time a device is found. Your blocking call needs to be repeated and repeated and repeated. Assuming the logic around that is fine (but I'd consider to keep this asynchronous model, why not?! where it doesn't fit?) then simply introduce another function that will wait a signal (signaled from event handler) before returning a found device

Comment: Current async model does not match my needs since I've my thread running an infinite loop like this: `scanForDevices()` -> `connectToDiscoveredDevices()` -> `sleepAWhile()`-> ...that's why I cannot find a way (my limitation) to use an async model in this procedure

Comment: The function we are talking about is the `scanForDevices()` : if it returns immediatly because it's async, the `connectToDiscoveredDevices()` always takes an empty devices vector as input. But maybe there's an another implementation/design I'm not aware of.

Comment: I don't know library you're using but what if you specify an infinite timeout? Will it continue searching? In that case it behaves like thread you're planning to write and you may just move connectToDiscoveredDevices() in the event handler.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti: after a timeout (cannot be infinite) the function return in any case, even if a device has not been found. If I move the connectToDiscoveredDevices() in the event handler then the thread goes immediatly in the sleep section, invalidating the initial scope to: "discover and connect to Bluetooth devices every n seconds"

Comment: Can you specify a 0 timeout? In that case you can connectTo() in event handler (but asynchronous in respect to your background thread...)

Answer (score 0):

What you want is a Semaphore which your main thread sits on until the discovery thread completes and then notifies your main thread to wake.

Active waits like what you suggest are nasty, and should be avoided where you can.